# Let $G$ be a set with an associative operation defined on it. Show that $G$ is group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Let $G$ be a set with an associative operation defined on it. Show that $G$ is group.

For all $g$ and $h$ in $G$, $gx=h$ has a unique solution in $G$.

**My attempt:**

A set $G$ has left cancellation property by uniqueness of solution of equation.

For any $a\in G$, $\exists e_a \in G$ such that $ae_a=a$.

$aa=(ae_a)a=a(e_aa) \implies e_aa=a$.

For $g \in G$, $\exists !h\in G$  such that $ah=g$.

Thus $ e_ag=e_a(ah)=(e_aa)h=ah=g$.

But I don't know how to make the equation $ge_a=g$ is vaild.

Comment: A set $G$ with an associative binary operation that satisfies that $gx=h$ has a unique solution for all $g$ and $h$ is **not** necessarily a group. For example, take $G=\{a,b\}$ with $a\neq b$, and define the operation by $xy=y$ for all $x,y\in G$. Verify that this is associative; $gx=h$ has the unique solution $x=h$. But $ab=bb$ with $a\neq b$, so $G$ cannot be a group.

Comment: Thanks you so much :)